# How do I find out where the focus is going in my WPF application?

Tags: wpf, focus, lost-focus, lostfocus

I have a search screen in my WPF application.  The screen is implemented as a UserControl in a TabItem of a TabControl.  When the user switches to the Search tab, I want the focus to go into one particular field.

So I added a Loaded event handler to the UserControl tag in the Xaml and I called the Focus method of the control I want to have the initial focus in the Loaded event handler.  This worked great until I upgraded the Telerik control library I'm using today.  Now, when I switch to the Search tab, the focus is NOT in the field I want to have it, but I can't tell what control does have the focus.

The field I want to have focus already has GotFocus & LostFocus event handlers for other reasons.  I remembered that in Win Forms, the LostFocus event handler arguments tell you which control is going to get the focus.  So I put a breakpoint in my LostFocus handler & discovered that the arguments to the LostFocus event handler in WPF don't include that information.

How can I figure out where the focus is going without putting GotFocus handlers on every control in my UserControl?

Tony

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try putting your breakpoint on the [`LostKeyboardFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.lostkeyboardfocus.aspx) Attached Event instead of the `LostFocus` Event. It uses the [`KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardfocuschangedeventargs.aspx) Class which does have properties that show which element had focus and where the focus is going.

```
private void textBox1_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = ((FrameworkElement)e.NewFocus).Name ; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed.  I couldn't tell easily where the focus was going because it went to a checkbox I have on the form, and this shows focus by putting a dashed box around the inside of the check box.  It's tiny & hard to see unless you're really looking for it.  At least, it is in my application.

Answer (score 10):

Try to press **Tab** Key and see if it helps you find the control in focus.

You can also use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) as suggested in this Q/A: [Any tips on debugging focus issues in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351442/any-tips-on-debugging-focus-issues-in-wpf)

> For starters, Snoop shows the current focused element and the current
>   FocusScope in the status bar.
>
> You can get it to show you all the GotFocus and LostFocus events:
>
> ```
> 1. Run your app.
> 2. Run Snoop.
> 3. Choose your app in the dropdown.
> 4. Click the binoculars ("Snoop") button.
> 5. On the right pane, click the Events tab.
> 6. Click to bring down the dropdown.
> 7. Scroll down to the Keyboard section and check GotKeyboardFocus, LostKeyboardFocus, and optionally the PreviewXXX events.
> 8. Now do what you need to do to manipulate focus and watch the Snoop window.
> ```
>
> Similarly you can track the FocusManager events the same way.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot in the morning.